# Trying to assign the target of a button in the super class

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, scope

I have a baseVc that all my `UIViewController` inherit from, all of which will have the same buttons in the `UINavigationBar`, if they are embedded in a `UINavigationController`.

What I am trying to do is set the target and action of one of these buttons from the child class, however I am having no luck. How can I get this to work?

```
@interface BaseVc : UIViewController  
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIBarButtonItem *actionButton;  

@end
```

Above is the header of my parent class, and in the child class:

```
[[super actionButton] setTarget:self];
[[super actionButton] setAction:@selector(viewMenu)];
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What "luck" are you not having?  Please show some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understand correctly, you should do next: assign action to the button inside the parent class, -doRightMenuButtonAction for example, and then just override this method in the child class and handle this action.

Comment: would I have to make that method public in the parent class?

Comment: No, just call it from child class. Don't forget to implement default method inside the parent class. You can call [super doRightMenuButtonAction] if there will be some common behavior or not override it at all, parent method realizaition will called then.

Answer (score 0):

As your subclass inherits from BaseVC, it can access actionButton property. So Jjust try:

```
[self.actionButton setTarget:self];
[self.actionButton setAction:@selector(viewMenu)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not marking your buttons as private.

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    var button  = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        button.frame  = CGRectMake(20, 200, 200, 44)
        button.setTitle("Hello World", forState: .Normal)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }
}
```

and then in your subclass...

```
    class AceViewController: BaseViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            button.addTarget(self, action: "sayHello:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        }

        func sayHello (button: UIButton) {
            UIAlertView(title: "Hello", message: "World", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "Ok").show()
        }
}
```